# Isomorphism of finite cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove this following result.

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ generated by $x$. Prove that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Here is my attempt.

> I claim that $G = \langle x \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Define the map
> \begin{align*}
> \varphi: \underset{\overline{a}\longmapsto x^a}{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to G}.
> \end{align*}
> Given $\overline{a}, \overline{b} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for which $\overline{a} = \overline{b}$, then $a = b + nq$ for some $n,q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we have
> \begin{align*}
> \varphi(\overline{a}) = x^a = x^{b + nq} = x^b (x^n)^q = x^b e^q = x^b e = x^b = \varphi(\overline{b}),
> \end{align*}
> so $\varphi$ is well-defined. Then, given $\overline{a}, \overline{b} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> \varphi\left(\overline{a} \overline{b}\right) = \varphi\left(\overline{ab}\right) = x^{ab} = x^a x^b = \varphi\left(\overline{a}\right) \varphi\left(\overline{b}\right),
> \end{align*}
> so $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. Then, given $g \in G$, we have $g = x^m$ for some $0 \leq m \leq n-1$. Then $\varphi(\overline{m}) = x^m = g$, so $\varphi$ is surjective. Finally, for $\overline{a}, \overline{b} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for which $\varphi(\overline{a}) = \varphi(\overline{b})$, we have $x^a = x^b$, so $x^{a-b} = e$, so $n \mid a - b$, i.e., $a \equiv b \text{ (mod $n$)}$, so $\overline{a} = \overline{b}$. So $\varphi$ is injective and hence bijective, so $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, and we have $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong G$.

How does this look?

Comment: In your definition of the map, I assume you meant $\overline{a}\mapsto x^a$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two mistakes in the last display (that canceled each other out, but each mistake is important to understand). First, the result of $\overline a\overline b$ (under the binary operation on $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$) is $\overline{a+b}$, not $\overline{ab}$. (Indeed, it's probably intended that the binary operation on $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ be written as $+$.) Second, $x^{ab}$ is not equal to $x^ax^b$ but rather to $(x^a)^b$. But since you should have $x^{a+b}$ anyway, you'll get to the right answer.

(Note also that because the two sets are finite, any surjective function is automatically injective.)

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you for pointing these out.